# css fill background image vertically to 100%

Tags: html, css, fill

I have a website with two margins as images. I use them as background for my divs.

When the page is loaded, if the parent is greater than window size the scrollbar will appear. The bars have a height:100% and they are filling only to the window size.

How can I solve this problem?

I want to make them work on almost all browsers, it's important to work even on IE7.

I may solve this with JS/JQuery but I would like to know if there is a better way to do this.

```
<body>
    <div id="left"><img src="Imagini/Left_01.jpg" alt="" /></div>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div id="left_edge"><img src="Imagini/LeftEdge.jpg" alt="" /></div>
        <div id="q">

        </div>
        <div id="right_edge"><img src="Imagini/rightedge_04.jpg" alt="" /></div>
    </form>
    <div id="right"><img src="Imagini/right_05.jpg" alt="" /></div>
</body>
</html>

body 
{
    margin:0 0 0 0;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-family:"Verdana", Sans-Serif;
}

#left 
{
    float:left;
    width: 116px;
}

#left_edge
{
    width:22px;
    float:left;
    min-height: 10px;
    height:100%;
    background: url('../Imagini/LeftEdge.jpg');
    background-repeat:repeat-y;
}

#form1
{
    background: #FAFAFA;
    width:700px;
    float:left;
}

#q 
{
    float:left;
    width:656px;
}

#right 
{
    width:693px;
    float:left;
}

#right_edge
{
    width:22px;
    float:left;
}
```

LATER EDIT: I am not talking about not having a scrollbar. I want that scrollbar to see the entire page but what I want is to vertically fill #left_edge and #right_edge with it's background to the entire height of it's parent

Please take a look at the [image]

The sides with shadows are missing.

Answer (score 0):

I just tryed and added this two into #left_edge and no scroll didnt appeared

```
position: fixed; 
overflow: hidden;
```